# vba: variable not defined in activeCell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba so am learning. I'm struggling to understand why this is failing in Excel 2016 and my research is drawing a blank. I have the following code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Range_End_Method()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveCell

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Do While rng.Value <> Empty
        If InStr(rng.Value, "Petrol") = 0 Then
            currentRow = ActiveCell.Row
            Worksheets("MySheet").Cells(currentRow, 5) = "Shopping"
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
            rng.Select
        Else
            currentRow = ActiveCell.Row
            Worksheets("MySheet").Cells(currentRow, 9) = "Not Found"
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
            rng.Select
        End If
   Loop

End Sub
```

If I open the vba editor and type this into a "Microsoft Excel Objects" sheet I don't get an error. But if I run as a "Modules" naming my module as "m_End" I get an error thrown up saying

```
Compile Error

Variable not defined
```

The variable it highlights in vba editor is "currentRow" from the line in the first "If condition":

```
currentRow = ActiveCell.Row
```

I don't understand what the difference is and how to fix the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a ***Sub*** statement at the beginning of your code.

Comment: At the beginning of your code you should have `Option Explicit` followed by `Sub yourSubName()`.  That being the case, you never declare `currentRow` as being a variable.  If you don't have `Option Explicit` at the beginning, go to `Tools ► Options ► Editor ► Code Settings` and Select `Require Variable Declaration`  It will save you loads of time in the future.  Perhaps in your sheet module you did not have `Option Explicit`

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my code - I mistakenly forgot to copy the option and sub statements. They were there as well when running the code. Which still gave the same error. How should I be declaring the variable? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you posted the rest of your code, that error is clearly because you did not declare `currentRow` in your `Dim` statements.  Possibly `option Explicit` was not in your sheet module, so no error.

In any event, go to `Tools ► Options ► Editor ► Code Settings` and Select `Require Variable Declaration` It will save you loads of debugging time in the future. Perhaps in your sheet module you did not have `Option Explicit`

I would declare it as a `Long`

Oh, and in VBA there is no advantage (and there are some disadvantages) to declaring a data type as `Integer`.  They get converted to Longs internally anyway; and the values which can be assigned are limited.  Check VBA specifications for data types for the various limits.

Comment: Great, that did it. I just checked and you are right my other code did not have the "option Explicit" tag. I just decalred as you mentioned and it works!!! Although the fields aren't getting set, but I'll try to debug that. Thanks